# How to get frequency spectrum from an audio wav file using fft.js with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fft, audio-processing

I'm trying to extract frequency information of simple 16 bit pcm wav file containing only one pure tone (750hz created with audacity) in JavaScript with nodejs.

I'm using:

- [node-wav](https://github.com/andreasgal/node-wav) for reading the wav file
- [fft.js](https://github.com/indutny/fft.js/) to perfom fft operation
- [nodeplotlib](https://github.com/ngfelixl/nodeplotlib) to finaly plot the results

Here is the code i came up with:

```js
const wav = require('node-wav');
const FFT = require('fft.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const plotlib = require('nodeplotlib');


let size = 4096; //fft size
let fft = new FFT(size); //create fft object
let realOutput = new Array(size); // to store final result
let complexOutput = fft.createComplexArray(); // to store fft output


let buffer = fs.readFileSync('750hz.wav'); // open a 1s wav file(mono 16bit pcm file at   32000hz) containing only a 750hz sinusoidal tone
let result = wav.decode(buffer); // read wav file data
let audioData = Array.prototype.slice.call( result.channelData[0]); // convert Float32Array to normal array
realInput = audioData.slice(0,size); // use only 4096 sample from the buffer.

fft.realTransform(complexOutput, realInput); // compute fft
// fft.completeSpectrum(complexOutput);
fft.fromComplexArray(complexOutput,realOutput); // get rid of the complex value and keep only real


let x =[];
for(let i=0;i<size;i++) x.push(i); //create a simple dumb x axis for the fft plot

plotlib.plot( // plotting the input data
    [{
        x: x,
        y: realInput,
        type: 'line',
        name:'input'
    }]
);

plotlib.plot( // plotting the fft output
    [{
        x: x,
        y: realOutput,
        type: 'line',
        name:'output'
    }]
);
```

Plotting the input data from the code above give me:
[image: input data]

And the output look like this:
[image: fft output]

While i was expecting to get **only one** spike, something like this:
[image: Audacity frequency spectrum plot]

1. **Is there something wrong with my code or the output is supposed to look like that and i missed something about how to generate frequency spectrum out of an fft?**
2. **Can fft work with float value right away or it need to be converted to Integer first?**
3. **Do i need the complex part of the fft output in my case?**

Comment: I think you can plot both plots from a single `plotlib.plot()` call (pass output plot object as second element). Also, maybe try `node-fft` package (aka fft-js).

Comment: It looks like you tested `completeSpectrum()`, but the docs says `realTransform()` only fills in half of the array. What does the fft output plot look like when using `completeSpectrum()`?

Comment: did you sort this out?